# Dynamic Parameter in url in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I am trying to set and get the value from the url in wordpress. What i mean is following;

My current page url

```
http://www.myurl.com/pageName
```

What i want is

```
http://www.myurl.com/pageName/some-dynamic-text
```

when i try to do so it redirect me to not found page. I only want to do this on one specific page

My permalink is  Post name `http://www.myurl.com/sample-post/`

Comment: "when i try to do so" - how exactly are you trying to do this? Please include in your question.

Comment: @CodeConfident "when i try to do so" is alreadyy explained in the question it means when i tried `http://www.myurl.com/pageName/some-dynamic-text`   it will redirect me to not found page and my page url is `http://www.myurl.com/pageName`

Comment: I asked you to clarify so we can help you. "when I try to do so" could mean anything; I expected you to have tried some kind of redirect mapping the latter URL to the former. Honestly I still don't know which URL you're expecting the user to click, which you want to show, or where the magic "some-dynamic-text" is coming from. If you want help you need to be as clear as possible.

Comment: @CodeConfident My problem is simple for example in wordpress i have a page named as pageName .. when i hit `http://www.myurl.com/pageName` it will open up the page ... what i want is to open exaclty the same page with `http://www.myurl.com/pageName/some-dynamic-text` "some-dynamic-text" could be anything for example `http://www.myurl.com/pageName/Hello` or `http://www.myurl.com/pageName/World` both url should redirect to same exact page ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `add_rewrite_rule`wordpress API, as shown https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: can you please explain it to me on my case

Comment: Perhaps something like this: `<?php add_rewrite_rule('(.+)\/.+', '$matches[1]', 'top'); ?>`. The RegEx pattern means "any character many times, up to the last slash, then at least one more character (the group captures up to the last slash).

Comment: Actually this is slightly better RegEx because it ignores multiple trailing slashes: `(.+)\/[^\/]+`